# Object.create() и this

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

```js
var Person = {
  constructor: function (name, age, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    return this;
  },
  greet: function () {
    console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name);
  }
};
var person, anotherPerson, thirdPerson;

person = Object.create(Person);
person.constructor('John', 35, 'male');
console.log(person.name);
```

Такая механика работает, в консоль выводится имя. Этот код работает даже если в constructor не возвращать this. Но... Если записать код таким образом

```
person = Object.create(Person).constructor('John', 35, 'male');
```

то есть сразу вызвать constructor и при этом не возвращать this в constructor то будет ошибка. Вопрос, можете ли объяснить механику работы первого и второго варианта, в чем их принципиальная разница? Почему при раздельном вызове все работает и без возврата this, а при вызове цепочкой происходит ошибка?

Comment: а вы уверены, что во втором варианте конструктор применяется к созданному объекту?

Comment: Думаю да, а к чему он может применяться ещё? Если нет, то поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, дело в следующем:

В 1м случае - ты создаешь сначала объект `person = {}` :

`Object.create(Person)` передает новый объект {} в переменную `person`, затем для `person = {}` вызывается `person.constructor()`

Во 2м случае, у тебя еще нет объекта `person ={}`:

`Object.create(Person)` возвращает `this` и сразу передает его не `person`, а на `constructor()`, который уже обрабатывает этот, пока еще безымянный объект и... вот тут вот и возникает `return this;` При его наличии, он передает полученный и обработанный **виртуальный** объект дальше по цепочке, и, т.к. цепочка закончилась он наконц приходит к переменной `person`, а, при его отсутствии, обработанный виртуальный объект просто уходит в никуда (т.е. удаляется)

UPD: Вот тебе более наглядный пример (заодно, в другом варианте использования Object.create, чтобы видно было, что это не только с constructor):

```
var val = {
  a: {value: function(){this.b=1; return 'какая-то хрень!';}}
}
o = Object.create({},val); //Вернет o = {a: function(){this.b=1; return 'какая-то хрень!';}}
var k = o.a();//Добавит в o b=1; и присвоит k текст  'какая-то хрень!'
```

А если сделаешь так:

```
o = Object.create({},val).a();// Получится o = 'какая-то хрень!'
```

И та же история, если в своем примере заменишь `return this;` на `return 'какая-то хрень!';`

Answer (score 0):

Выше написано много слов, напишу проще.

Когда есть вот такой код:

```
person = Object.create(Person).constructor('John', 35, 'male');
```

то в переменную `person` попадает результат вызова метода `constructor`. Что вернули - то и попало. Вернули `this` - попало `this`. Ничего не вернули - ничего не попало ("ничего" в js называется `undefined`).

Comment: здравствуйте, могли бы вы дать ссылку на то, где можно почитать  про механику такого "возвращения" при создании объекта `person`?  То, что вы написали выглядит логично, но хотелось бы почитать теорию, где это подробно описано, если конечно таковая существует!

Comment: @Muranx здесь нет ничего специфичного для "создания" объектов, это обычный вызов метода

Comment: @Muranx а читать лучше всего спецификацию языка, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-intro